# CSS/JS- Split image in two animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I would love to animate my web page using CSS and JS.  My first webpage is made of one image centered horizontally and vertically and I would love this one to split into two images, one that goes up and on that goes down, so that my second webpage appears. I just don't know how can I split my image into two.

My HTML is basically made of

```
<div class="page1">
      <img src="img/LogoEpaissiBlanc.png" alt="Logo" id="logoindex1">
</div>
```

and my CSS :

```
.page1 {
height: 723px;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}


#logoindex1{
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
width: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you'll have to split the image into two using photoshop or some similar tool and keep the images together using css. Then add a transition that makes one half to move in one direction and the other image to move in the other direction.

This [link](https://designshack.net/articles/css/perform-a-split-reveal-with-css/) might help.

Comment: I thought about it, but i was wondering if a CSS/JS solution exists.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than splitting your image in two, you could set it as the background of two `div`s, each sized to be half the size of your whole image. The left image would have `background-position: left` and the right image would have `background-position: right;`

Here's a fiddle to get you started: https://jsfiddle.net/tf45z2cy/

```
#img-left, #img-right {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/100/100");
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
#img-right {
  background-position: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to know what really you want to do, **split an image into two pieces?** or **two images one goes up and one goes down?**

If the case is with two images you can visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193749/how-to-split-an-image-responsive-into-two-div-blocks-using-css), in the answers, you will see how to split to images, something like this:

```css
#image {
    position: relative;
 width: 200px;
}

#half-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="image">
  <img src='https://placehold.it/200x200' id='outer' class='img-responsive'>
    <div id = "half-image">
      <img src='https://placehold.it/200/e8117f' id = 'inner'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you need to need to animate your images to move, you can use [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) to your images.
View the source code on GitHub [here](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css). In the `README` file he explains it how to use it!

```css
#left {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
}

#right {
  float: right;
}
    

.fadeOutDown {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeOutDown;
  -moz-animation-name: fadeOutDown;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.fadeOutUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeOutUp;
  -moz-animation-name: fadeOutUp;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@3.5.2/animate.min.css">

<div id="left">
 <img src='https://cdn.abranhe.com/stackoverflow/48027310/left.png' class="animated fadeOutDown" >
 <div id = "right">
  <img src='https://cdn.abranhe.com/stackoverflow/48027310/right.png'  class="animated fadeOutUp" >
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=PoLx0x9dhF Here is my project. 

What I want to do is to split my round logo into two halfs. One that goes up and one down. Like if it was a pokeball that opens. 

I don't know if I am clear enough. I hope though.

Comment: Now I got what you basically want, what I did was to cut the image into two different pictures I will edit my answer, hope you help you out! check it out.

Comment: Maybe you need to cut your image in half properly.